# where is the staticlib for opencv 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv3.1

I just noted that openCV 3.1 is released, but when I download the binary files for windows, I noted that there is no static lib for this release.

Is it a mistake or official that static libs will not be included into official binary release?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV provide all-in-one lib from 3.0 version, locates in build/x64/vc12(vc14)
opencv_world310.lib

If you want libs like 2.x version try to build lib and dll with cmake by yourself

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this isn't a static lib as we can see in OpenCv 3.0 (which resides in opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib) This libraries don't need any dll.

Comment: use cmake to rebuild from source code, you will get a sln(solution) of Visual Studio, this sln contains all source project, and then open the solution in VS, you can choose generate staticlib or dll